# Ubuntu 9.10 in Virtual PC video issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, microsoft-virtual-pc

After a clean install of Ubuntu 9.10 in Virtual PC 2007 the screen looks like the one in the image below. There's no X installed, I only want to access the terminal. How can I address this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Virtual PC isn't very compatible with Linux.

Try [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (free) or VMWare (not free, but well worth the money.)

Comment: Good advice. Unfortunately installing Virtual Box is not an option on this system because it wants to add some drivers which are not certified by Microsoft.

Comment: just curious (I am not a windows user). Are you saying that windows does not let install what you want unless Microsoft approves of that first?

Comment: @mac: Yeah, but remember Virtual PC is free.  It appears Ubuntu runs fine on HyperV

Comment: @mac: I think it's a domain policy applied to this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer) article to see if disabling the framebuffer helps you get your console back.

You could also look at [This](http://arcanecode.com/2008/04/24/installing-ubuntu-804-under-microsoft-virtual-pc-2007/) post for further information and work arounds.

Hope this helps. These tips will also apply to any other GNU/Linux distribution if it suffers similiar problems.

Comment: No success with these. It seems the grub configuration is different in 9.10 and I could not find the values mentioned in the article.